# WP7 Custom User Control Property

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want a user control called Segmented Panel that contains 3 buttons of which I want to modify their names (Title1/2/3) from a XAML screen.

MainPage XAML:

```
<local:SegmentedControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,62,0,0" x:Name="segmentedControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Title1="ENTER BUTTON NAME HERE" Title2="blah.." Title3="Last Button" Loaded="segmentedControl1_Loaded" />
```

SegmentedControl XAML.CS:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Title1Property
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Title1", typeof(String), typeof(StackPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static void SetTitle1(UIElement element, String value) {
        element.SetValue(Title1Property, value);
    }
    public static string GetTitle1(UIElement element) {
        return (string)element.GetValue(Title1Property);
    }

    public string Title1 {
        get { return GetValue(Title1Property).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(Title1Property, value); }
    }
```

In expression blend I open up the Segmented Panel, choose button1, in Content I tried chosing both *Data Context* and *Element Value*, then scrolling down to choose "Title1", but when I compile it, the button's contents never changes.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: i don't get it.  you're adding an attached property to StackPanel, but your type is SegmentedControl?  did you mean to declare your dependency properties on typeof(SegmentedControl) instead?

Answer (score 0):

as John Gardner suggests, you have to write ...typeof(SegmentedControl) in your dependency property implementation and then one have to bind the property to the appropiate UI element!

For example:

```
<local:SegmentedControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="43,62,0,0" x:Name="segmentedControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Title1="{Binding Title1}" ... Loaded="segmentedControl1_Loaded" />
```